# Reusable ContentView in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a contentview separately, so that I can reuse the same in different ContentPage.

Here is my ContentView.XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:MyMXLibrary.Helpers"
         x:Class="MyMXLibrary.Views.AlertView" 
         x:Name="this">
<ContentView.Content>
    <Frame VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=Heading}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=Message}"/><Label Text="Cancel">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" />
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
            <Label Text="Ok">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ProceedCommand}" />
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</ContentView.Content></ContentView>
```

Here is my ContentView.Xaml.cs

```
 public partial class AlertView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty HeadingTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Heading), typeof(string), typeof(Label));
     public static readonly BindableProperty MessageTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Message), typeof(string), typeof(Label));

    public string Heading { get { return (string)GetValue(HeadingTextProperty); } set { SetValue(HeadingTextProperty, value); } }
    public string Message { get { return (string)GetValue(MessageTextProperty); } set { SetValue(MessageTextProperty, value); } }

    public AlertView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }      
}
```

Here is my sample ContentPage.Xaml where I'm planning to reuse the above created content view.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          xmlns:alert="clr-namespace:MyMXLibrary.Views"
         x:Class="MyMXLibrary.Views.MyPage"
         Title="MyPage"><ContentPage.Content><ContentView >
      <alert:AlertView Heading="Test" Message="Sample" ></alert:AlertView></ContentView></ContentPage.Content></ContentPage>
```

it's working fine if  I use a static value. But instead, if I bind the value

```
<alert:AlertView Heading="Test" Message="{Binding sample}" ></alert:AlertView>
```

I'm getting error

```
No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Message', or mismatching type between value and property
```

How can I do the Binding here. Since my value is unknown I cannot assign a stactic value in XAML, I have to go with Binding only. 
What Should I do here to bind the value, please help me.

Comment: what is the type of the "sample" property you're binding to?

Comment: Sample is just a string value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have the BindableProperty creation code wrong. You have:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty HeadingTextProperty = 
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Heading), typeof(string), typeof(Label));
public static readonly BindableProperty MessageTextProperty = 
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Message), typeof(string), typeof(Label));
```

So the third parameter is `typeof(Label)` but it should be the type of the class that will have the property, in this case `AlertView`. Also by convention (not sure if required) the bindable property name will be the property name + "Property". You have property name + "TextProperty". So try:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty HeadingProperty = 
    BindableProperty.Create("Heading", typeof(string), typeof(AlertView));
public static readonly BindableProperty MessageProperty = 
    BindableProperty.Create("Message", typeof(string), typeof(AlertView));
```

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#creating-a-property) for more info. You will see that the 3rd parameter of the `BindableProperty.Create` method is the `declaringType` which should be the type that is defining the bindable property.

**sample project:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/j7kpehpt8htrf8k/TestAlertView.zip?dl=0

Comment: I tried the way you mentioned. But still the same issue. I have seen lot of reusable content view sample, all has the static value assigned in XAML. Does not bind any value.

Comment: I just confirmed that this works on my end. I added a link to a sample project that demonstrates the binding working after making the changes I noted.

Comment: OMG !!! I don't know where the mistake is. But copying the code from your link , works fine. I wasted a day for solving this issue :-(